# Login Error using Spring Boot, WebSecurity and JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use spring security to handle the login and logout of users.
Pages that need to be accesible without login are accesible and vice versa.
I also can register, but when I try to sign in nothing happens.

I don't get a error nothing, the loginpage refreshes that's all...

My WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Autowired
private @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource;

@Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
private String usersQuery;

@Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
private String rolesQuery;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.
            jdbcAuthentication()
            .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.
            authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/users/**").hasAuthority("USER").anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .failureForwardUrl("/loginError")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/change")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/loginError");
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
}
}
```

My loginController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("login")
public class LoginController {
@Autowired
private LoginService loginService;
private String referrer = "loginSucces";

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleGet(ModelMap model, HttpSession session, 
HttpServletRequest request) {
    referrer = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.REFERER);
    if (session.getAttribute("username") != null) {
        return "home";
    }
    model.addAttribute("returnPreviousPage", referrer);
    User loginForm = new User();
    model.put("loginForm", loginForm);
    return "login";
}

//SpringBoot should do this automaticly?
/*   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processLogin(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") User user, 
Map<String, Object> model) {
    String username = user.getUsername();
    String password = user.getPassword();
    String message;
    if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
        message = "Sorry, can't leave any fields empty.\nPlease Try again.";
        return new ModelAndView("login", "message", message);
    }
    if (loginService.checkUsercredentials(username, password)) {
        message = "Login Succes, Welkom " + username + "!";
        return new ModelAndView("home", "message", message);
    } else {
        message = "Sorry, invalid login credentials.\nPlease Try again.";
        return new ModelAndView("login", "message", message);
    }
}*/
}
```

Anyone an Idea of what's going wrong?

Comment: Where is the targeted controller after success authentication, in your config it is mapped to `/change` .

Comment: Change is a copy of the homepage and and the controller return the change view, change is redundant now. That's from before spring security, cause users couldn't use the function on the homepage. But even when I return "/" the result is the same